# How to use relative file path for firefox profile in Selenium webdriver using java?

Tags: java, webdriver

I want to use relative file path in Firefoxprofile function, I have tried all possible ways but its throwing error.
Here is my code-
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "/downloaded_files/");

folder "downloaded_files" is saved in root directory of my project. I tried all combinations of /,//,\ still its not downloading filed in desired folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "./downloaded_files/");
```

Or

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", workingDir +"/downloaded_files/");
```